# ArgumentMatchers in MockK

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

I'm converting from Java to Kotlin, and from Mockito to MockK.

I'm stuck at converting Argument Matchers from Mockito to MockK.

Mockito can do `any()` to match **anything**, including nulls and varargs. (imports ArgumentMatchers.any)

For example:

```
verify(object1).store(any(SomeClass.class));
```

Does MockK have anything for that? In this specific situation, it's not any primitive type. I'm trying to match a class Object.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match a specific type, you could do

```
verify { object1.store(ofType(SomeClass::class)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

In mockk, you can `any()` like this.

```
verify { object1.store(any()) }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of migrate of Mockito to Mockk, consider the following:

With Mockito is encapsuled the class inside verify method, for example:

```
verify(object1).store(any(SomeClass.class));
```

In Mockk use lambda with receiver, similar to apply function (but without return), for example:

```
verify{ object1.store(any<SomeClass::class>()) }
```

And response your question, for specify the type can use any<YourType::class>, although the compiler marks it as unnecessary code because it has type inference, This is mainly useful when you have overloaded a function, so you can differentiate which parameters to receive for each one, for example:

```
class YourClass {
    fun someMethod(value: String) {
    }

    fun someMethod(value: Int) {
    }
}


fun test() {
    val mock: YourClass = mockk()
    verify { mock.someMethod(any<String>()) }
    verify { mock.someMethod(any<Int>()) }
}
```